# mysql error says i have a syntax error but i don't understand the error message

Tags: mysql

I'll attach the images and the error messsage.

Here is my first table in my DB.

[image]

Here is the error message that I'm getting:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatype is `INT` but you are trying to give it default values like an ENUM.

Comment: oh crap.. stupid mistake.. thank you for pointing that out. =/

Answer (score 0):

INT is not an enum. You have to put a numerical value in that field. not '0', '1'

For example, INT 11